# preg_replace replace \ before echo variable

Tags: variables, preg-replace

I have following variable `$row_messageRepliesResults['msgReplyText']` and below data inside database for this variable

```
Your website <a href=\"http://www.example.com/link.php\" target=\"\" rel=\"\">http://www.example.com/links.php</a> was without any content \"not guaranteeing CTR\".
```

the problem I have is that when I echo variable with this content those \ appear too, so I was wondering how to use `preg_replace` in order to get rid of them. I tried something but always get blank data.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all strings are similar to this one (no escape characters except quotes) you don't need to use `preg_replace()`; a simple [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do.

```
$newstring=str_replace("\\","",$row_messageRepliesResults['msgReplyText']);
```